# How do I prove that A∩B∩C can be zero?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a situation where,

```
n(A)=a
n(B)=b
n(C)=c

n(A∩B)=x
n(B∩C)=y
n(C∩A)=z

where a,b,c,x,y,z>0
```

Although I do understand that A∩B∩C can be `{0,min(x,y,z)}` but how do I prove that it can attain the value 0?

Comment: If you understand *why* $A\cap B\cap C$ can be anything between $0$ and $\min(x,y,z)$ then you know how it can be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Just find three sets with this property: you're just trying to show that it *can* happen, so one example is sufficient.

Comment: Yes that'd definitely work,  I was just looking for some general proof , if there is one. Just the way I can prove `min(x,y,z)` for the upper bound I'd like a proof for the lower bound.

Comment: I can't conceive of any useful way to define "general proof" that doesn't include an example in this case.

Comment: min(x,y,z) was a proof of what *couldn't* be. You couldn't have the intersection be larger. To prove it can be 0 is a proof of what *can* be and the only thing nescessary for that is a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

"How do I prove that $A \cap B \cap C$ can be zero?"

Sometimes a figure is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks for the figure, I had the same figure in mind I was just wondering if there was a way I could prove it just the way the upper bound `min(x,y,z)` is proved.

Comment: min(x,y,z) was a proof of what *couldn't* be. You couldn't have the intersection be larger. To prove it can be 0 is a proof of what *can* be and the only thing nescessary for that is a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

$\min(x,y,z)$ was a proof of what *couldn't* be.  You couldn't have the intersection be larger.  To prove it can be $0$ is a proof of what *can* be and the only thing nescessary for that is a simple example.

There are eight *DISJOINT* sets that combine to make the whole enchilada.  They are (using the notation $M'$ to mean the compliment of $M$)

$A \cap B \cap C$ and $A\cap B \cap C'$ and $A \cap B' \cap C$ and $A \cap B' \cap C'$ and $A' \cap B \cap C$ and $A'\cap B \cap C'$ and $A' \cap B' \cap C$ and $A' \cap B' \cap C'$.

Any of these sets can contain any elements you desire so long as they are disjoint.  Simply leave $A \cap B\cap C$ empty.

You will have

$A \cap B = (A\cap B \cap C) \cup (A\cap B\cap C')$ so just make sure $A\cap B\cap C$ has no elements and $A\cap B \cap C'$ has $x$ elements.

$B\cap C = (A\cap B \cap C)\cup (A'\cap B\cap C)$ so make sure $(A'\cap B\cap C)$ has $y$ elements.

$A\cap C = (A\cap B\cap C) \cup (A\cap B' \cap C)$ so make sure $(A\cap B' \cap C)$ has $z$ elements.

Then $A = (A\cap B\cap C) \cup (A\cap B\cap C') \cup (A\cap B' \cap C)\cup (A\cap B'\cap C')$.  You can fill $A\cap B'\cap C'$ with as many elements or no elements as you wish.  Fill it with $k$ elements and you have $|A| = a = x+z + k$.

Then $B = (A\cap B\cap C) \cup (A\cap B\cap C') \cup (A'\cap B \cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap C')$.  You can fill $A'\cap B\cap C'$ with as many elements or no elements as you wish.  Fill it with $j$ elements and you have $|B| = b = x+y + j$.

Then $C = (A\cap B\cap C) \cup (A\cap B'\cap C) \cup (A'\cap B \cap C)\cup (A'\cap B'\cap C)$.  You can fill $A'\cap B'\cap C$ with as many elements or no elements as you wish.  Fill it with $m$ elements and you have $|C| = c = y+z + m$.

And that's it.  That's a proof.